# Skip bytes before download java/http

Tags: java, http, url, httpsurlconnection

I'm downloading data from a download link (the link that e.g. a download button contains on a website). This through HttpsURLConnection class. 
It is working fine so far just that I have no idea how to skip bytes when the file is for example already half downloaded.
I don't mean the InputStream.skip() method because this doesn't prevent internet use (it just skips bytes while downloading).
What I want is a way to tell the server/input stream to start downloading at a certain byte of the file.

Greetings,

Lucas

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests

Comment: Use what @JBNizet mentioned, assuming the server supports range requests. It probably will only work for static content.

Comment: Thanks @JB Nizet

Comment: Okay tried it out works perfect thanks =D